# Native application, Alarm API doesn't work (Sample Tizen Studio project)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am writing an app which functionality is to activate an alarm with few second delay, the alarm manager according to logs is being activated and sets an alarm however after defined time nothing happens.

Assuming i am doing something wrong, i have tried running sample project from Tizen Studio library, this project run on my Galaxy Watch is not able to run any alarm as well.

Code i am using in my app to set an alarm 10 seconds in front:

```
app_control_h app_control = NULL;
app_control_create(&app_control);
app_control_set_operation(app_control, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_MAIN);
app_control_set_app_id (app_control, "org.example.pushreceiver");
int alarm_id = 1;
int ret1 = 0;
struct tm date;
ret1 = alarm_get_current_time(&date);
date.tm_sec += 10;
ret1 = alarm_schedule_once_at_date(app_control, &date, &alarm_id);
```

Logs when alarm is set:

```
04-04 19:37:45.015 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __alarm_next_duetime_once(155) > Final due_time = 1554399495, Thu Apr  4 19:38:15 2019
04-04 19:37:45.303 : Error / WMS ( 3709 : 3709 ) : wms_package_manager.c: _wms_pkg_mgr_cb_watch_app_filter(843) > PKG[org.example.alarm], App[alarm], Version[2.3.2]
04-04 19:37:45.743 : Error / WMS ( 3709 : 3709 ) : wms_package_manager.c: _wms_pkg_mgr_cb_watch_app_filter(843) > PKG[com.samsung.alarm-solis], App[Alarm], Version[1.1.57]
04-04 19:37:45.979 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(447736985) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:45.979 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(573079649) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:45.979 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(783848223) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:45.979 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(1694750646) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:45.979 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(2142377266) is OVER.
```

Logs when alarm should take place:

```
04-04 19:37:47.143 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(447736985) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:47.143 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(573079649) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:47.143 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(783848223) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:47.143 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(1694750646) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:47.143 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(2142377266) is OVER.
04-04 19:37:47.151 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __alarm_next_duetime_once(155) > Final due_time = 1554399482, Thu Apr  4 19:38:02 2019
04-04 19:37:51.851 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 5012 : 5012 ) : alarm-lib.c: alarmmgr_add_alarm_appsvc_with_localtime(874) > start(4-4-2019, 19:37:61), end(0-0-0), repeat(0), interval(0), type(0)
04-04 19:37:51.919 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __alarm_next_duetime_once(208) > Final due_time = 1554399481, Thu Apr  4 19:38:01 2019
04-04 19:37:51.943 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 5012 : 5012 ) : alarm-lib.c: __alarmmgr_init_appsvc(737) > alarm was already initialized.
04-04 19:38:01.091 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager.c: __alarm_expired(1976) > Unable to run app svc
04-04 19:38:01.095 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(447736985) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:01.095 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(573079649) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:01.095 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(783848223) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:01.095 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(1694750646) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:01.095 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(2142377266) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:02.015 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(447736985) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:02.015 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(573079649) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:02.015 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(783848223) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:02.015 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(1694750646) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:02.015 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2669 : 2669 ) : alarm-manager-schedule.c: __find_next_alarm_to_be_scheduled(536) > The duetime of alarm(2142377266) is OVER.
04-04 19:38:02.031 : Warning / ALARM_MANAGER ( 2900 : 2900 ) : alarm-lib.c: __handle_expiry_method_call(221) > [alarm-lib] Call expired callback
04-04 19:38:02.031 : Info / PUSHD ( 2900 : 2900 ) : polling.c: _alarm_connection_lifetime_cb(930) > epoch_start[1554399482]
04-04 19:38:02.031 : Error / PUSHD ( 2900 : 2900 ) : spp.c: _clear_alarm(465) > No alarm to clear
04-04 19:38:02.031 : Error / PUSHD ( 2900 : 2900 ) : spp.c: _clear_alarm(465) > No alarm to clear
04-04 19:38:02.043 : Info / PUSHD ( 2900 : 2900 ) : polling.c: polling_stop_alarm(1027) > epoch_start[1554399482]
04-04 19:38:02.043 : Info / PUSHD ( 2900 : 2900 ) : polling.c: _clear_alarm(969) > epoch_start[1554399482]
```

I am unable to use alarm API at all even with the Tizen Studio sample project, for now i have tried changing the project API version from 4.0 to 2.3.2 with no effect.
Does anyone have a working alarm native project as a sample?

Answer (score 2):

your code looks perfectly ok. I checked your code with my own remote application and reproduced your scenario. The problem is that your application probably does not have the "http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch" privilege.

Please check logs from CYNARA security framework:

```
sdb dlog AMD_CYNARA_CORE:V
```

for

```
E/AMD_CYNARA_CORE( 2492): amd_cynara_core.c: __cynara_simple_checker(258) > cynara denied (http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch|(null)|(null)|(null))
```

When I added mentioned privilege to application, your code worked well. Please check with your app.